# Idiomatic way to feed multithreaded output to a single thread in modern Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, java-stream, forkjoinpool

I have this code which works fine. This question is focused on code maintainability, writing less code to accomplish the same goal:

```
                Queue<IncomingItem[]> queue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();
                IncomingItem[] EOF = new IncomingItem[0];

                ForkJoinPool.commonPool().submit(() -> {
                    IncomingItem[] next;
                    while((next = queue.poll()) != EOF) {
                        if(next == null) {
                            try {
                                Thread.sleep(1000);
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                throw new RuntimeException(e);
                            }
                            continue;
                        }
                        dao.batchInsert(next);
                    }
                });
                ds.reload(queue::add);
                queue.add(EOF);
                ForkJoinPool.commonPool().awaitQuiescence(1, TimeUnit.HOURS);
```

The purpose is to have the output from `ds.reload`, which is a heavily multi-threaded method, feed into the `dao.batchInsert` method, which is non-threadsafe non-thread-shareable (e.g. it is a Hibernate based DAO), while never blocking the `ds.reload` method, as would happen if the `dao.batchInsert` method were made `synchronized`.

This code was Java 8 compatible. Is there anything that has come out in newer Java releases which would enable a more elegant solution?

Comment: Unless you're looking at moving to something like RxJava, pushing to a concurrent queue is generally the best option. (Although I've also used a single-threaded executor for this particular task, which makes it easier to test the logic as it's an enclosed `Runnable`.)

Comment: [Flow](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Flow.html), introduced in Java 9, might do what you want.  There is a general implementation of Flow.Publisher, [SubmissionPublisher](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/SubmissionPublisher.html).

Answer (score 1):

Using thread pool here is a needless complication. Use dedicated thread. Instead of polling and sleeping, use blocking queue.

```
            BlockingQueue<IncomingItem[]> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
            IncomingItem[] EOF = new IncomingItem[0];
            Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
                IncomingItem[] next;
                while((next = queue.take()) != EOF) {
                    dao.batchInsert(next);
                }
            });
            thread.start();
            ds.reload(queue::put);
            queue.add(EOF);
            thread.join();
```